# C# Bitmap class as field?

Tags: c#, bitmap, null, field

I'm trying to make this class for processing images, and I wanted it to have a Bitmap field, and a constructor that would allow me to give to path to the bitmap so other methods could use that bitmap. So I wanted it to be able to do this:

```
ImageProcessing image = new ImageProcessing("D:\\image.bmp");
int time_of_processing = image.grayscale();
image.SaveTo("D:\\image2.bmp");
```

And so this is my code:

```
public class ImageProcessing
{
    Bitmap image;

    public ImageProcessing(string path)
    {
        image = new Bitmap(path);
    }

    public int Grayscale()
    {
        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();

        time.Start();
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                int grayScale = (int)((pixelColor.R * 0.21) + (pixelColor.G * 0.72) + (pixelColor.B * 0.07));
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
                image.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
            }
        }
        time.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = time.Elapsed;
        int milliseconds = ts.Milliseconds + (ts.Seconds * 1000);

        return milliseconds;

    }

    public void SaveTo(string path)
    {
        image.Save(path);
    }
}
```

And when i have this, Visual Studio tells me that image will always be null. How should the constructor look for it to work?

Comment: For starters, show the real code that actually produces the error message you are talking about... ;)

Comment: Since you have bitmap as one of the filed which should you garbage collected, I would suggest to implement the Idisposable on the ImageProcessing class and use Using around it.

Comment: This code does not produce the error you are talking about.  It may be a glitch in VS.  Try to do a clean and rebuild, or restart VS?  The only error is that you have not capitalized the call to grayscale()

Comment: Another minor flaw in your logic.  if you want to return the total milliseconds, return (int)ts.TotalMilliseconds.  There's no need to do all that calculation (which is flawed) because its not using TotalSeconds.

Comment: Visual underlined "Bitmap image;" with a green line and gave the CS0649  error (image will always be null). When I changed the name of the class from Class1 to ImageProcessing that error dissapeared. Maybe it was a glitch or smth, i don't know but thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Although now when I try to use it the error says that there is no constructor that takes 1 arguements. And the same goes when I try 0 or 2 arguments. This is actually a class (the only one) in a library I wanted to make, and when I try to use it:
      ImageProcessing obrazek = new ImageProcessing("a");

it gives me that constructor error. And I added the using namespaces of course

Comment: No, it was not a glitch. Think about where you did assign a Class1 object to the image field (before changing the field type to ImageProcessing)? You didn't, did you?

Comment: You seem to have several ImageProcessing classes. Go on the type declaration of the variable where the compiler complains about the constructor, and press F12. That will make VS jump to the declaration of that particular ImageProcessing class it tries to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the namespace to the ImageProcessing class when you use it to make sure its always using the correct class.  The following code (which is mostly just the original code) has been tested and works (it grayscales the image listed).

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string path1 = @"C:\work\test.bmp";
        string path2 = @"C:\work\test2.bmp";
        WindowsFormsApplication10.ImageProcessing image = new WindowsFormsApplication10.ImageProcessing(path1);
        int time_of_processing = image.Grayscale();
        image.SaveTo(path2);

    }
}

public class ImageProcessing
{
    Bitmap image;

    public ImageProcessing(string path)
    {
        image = new Bitmap(path);
    }

    public int Grayscale()
    {
        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();

        time.Start();
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                int grayScale = (int)((pixelColor.R * 0.21) + (pixelColor.G * 0.72) + (pixelColor.B * 0.07));
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
                image.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
            }
        }
        time.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = time.Elapsed;
        int milliseconds = ts.Milliseconds + (ts.Seconds * 1000);
        return milliseconds;

    }

    public void SaveTo(string path)
    {
        image.Save(path);
    }
}
}
```